# Можно ли параметр, передаваемый по значению, заменить аргументом переменной?

Tags: c#, функции, теория

Похоже совсем запутался, разбирая этот вопрос

Я так понимаю, что да, и выглядит это все добро всего лишь

```
double func(int x){};
int y = 22;
double z = func(y);
```

где y - как раз аргумент переменная, которая передается по значению, верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формулировка исходного вопроса конечно неграмотная, поэтому рискну предположить, что означает она необходимость продемонстрировать знание [ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) (внимательно читаем примечание в статье) и/или [out](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) модификаторов для параметров методов.

Тогда при изменении определения метода, например, на:

```
double func(ref int x)
{ 
    int a = x;
    x = 33;
    return a;
};
```

любое изменения значения параметра внутри функции будет передано в переменную, которая была указана при вызове.

```
int y = 22;
double z = func(ref y);// z = 22.0, y = 33
```

Для out логика немного другая, но это сами можете почитать в документации.

По поведению это похоже на передачу переменной, но передается на самом деле ссылка на область памяти, которая сопоставлена с переменной, сама переменная ни куда не передается. Это очень старый способ передачи параметров по ссылке и появился задолго до появления .NET, разделения типов на значимые и ссылочные и прочих модных и не очень языков и технологий, например в Fortran, Pascal и других давно забытых языках это было именно так, разве что out не было, так в нем и необходимости не было.